# SERP Scraping with Beautiful Soup

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I'm trying to build a simple script to scrape Google's first Search Results Page and export the results in .csv.
I managed to get URLs and Titles, but I cannot retrieve Descriptions.
I have been using the following code:

```
import urllib
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

# desktop user-agent
USER_AGENT = "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10.14; rv:65.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/65.0"
# mobile user-agent
MOBILE_USER_AGENT = "Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; Android 7.0; SM-G930V Build/NRD90M) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/59.0.3071.125 Mobile Safari/537.36"

query = "pizza recipe"
query = query.replace(' ', '+')
URL = f"https://google.com/search?q={query}"

headers = {"user-agent": USER_AGENT}
resp = requests.get(URL, headers=headers)

if resp.status_code == 200:
    soup = BeautifulSoup(resp.content, "html.parser")
    results = []
    for g in soup.find_all('div', class_='r'):
        anchors = g.find_all('a')
        if anchors:
            link = anchors[0]['href']
            title = g.find('h3').text
            desc = g.select('span')
            description = g.find('span',{'class':'st'}).text
            item = {
                "title": title,
                "link": link,
                "description": description
            }
            results.append(item)

import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame(results)
df.to_excel("Export.xlsx")
```

I get the following message when I run the code:

```
description = g.find('span',{'class':'st'}).text
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'text'
```

Essentially, the field is empty.

Can somebody please help me this line so that I can get all the information from the snippet?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not within the div class="r". It's under div class="s"

So change to this for description:

```
description = g.find_next_sibling("div", class_='s').find('span',{'class':'st'}).text
```

From the current element, it'll find the next div, with class="s". Then you can pull out the `<span>` tag

Answer (score 0):

Try to use [`select_one()` or `select()`](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#css-selectors) `bs4` methods. They're more flexible and easy to read. `CSS` selectors [reference](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_selectors.asp).

Also, you can [pass URL `params`](https://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/user/quickstart/#passing-parameters-in-urls) since `requests` do everything for you like so:

```py
# instead of this:
query = "pizza recipe"
query = query.replace(' ', '+')
URL = f"https://google.com/search?q={query}"

# try to use this:
params = {
  'q': 'fus ro dah', # query
  'hl': 'en'
}

requests.get('URL', params=params)
```

If you want to write to `.csv` then you need to use [`.to_csv()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_csv.html) rather than `.to_excel()`

If you want to get rid of `pandas` index column, then you can pass `index=False`, e.g `df.to_csv('FILE_NAME', index=False)`

---

Code and [example in the online IDE](https://replit.com/@DimitryZub1/QuixoticBlaringWorkspace#main.py):

```py
import pandas as pd
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


headers = {
  "User-agent":
  "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/70.0.3538.102 Safari/537.36 Edge/18.19582"
}

params = {
  'q': 'fus ro dah', # query
  'hl': 'en'
}

resp = requests.get("https://google.com/search", headers=headers, params=params)

if resp.status_code == 200:
    soup = BeautifulSoup(resp.text, "html.parser")

    results = []

    for result in soup.select('.tF2Cxc'):
      title = result.select_one('.DKV0Md').text
      link = result.select_one('.yuRUbf a')['href']
      snippet = result.select_one('#rso .lyLwlc').text

      item = {
        "title": title,
        "link": link,
        "description": snippet
      }

      results.append(item)

df = pd.DataFrame(results)
df.to_csv("BS4_Export.csv", index=False)
```

---

Alternatively, you can do the same thing by using [Google Organic Results API](https://serpapi.com/organic-results) from SerpApi. It's a paid API with a free plan.

The difference in your case is that you don't need to figure out what selectors to use and why they don't work although they should since it's already done for the end-user.

Code to integrate:

```py
from serpapi import GoogleSearch
import os
import pandas as pd

params = {
  "api_key": os.getenv("API_KEY"),
  "engine": "google",
  "q": "fus ro dah",
  "hl": "en"
}

search = GoogleSearch(params)
results = search.get_dict()

data = []

for result in results['organic_results']:
  title = result['title']
  link = result['link']
  snippet = result['snippet']

  data.append({
    "title": title,
    "link": link,
    "snippet": snippet
  })

df = pd.DataFrame(results)
df.to_csv("SerpApi_Export.csv", index=False)
```

P.S - I wrote a bit more detailed blog post about how to scrape [Google Organic Results](https://dev.to/dimitryzub/scrape-google-organic-search-with-python-3hp5).

> Disclaimer, I work for SerpApi.

Answer (score 0):

Analyzing Google’s pages may not be the best approach, as Google’s HTML tags frequently change over time and in their usage.

The result Google serp api(custom search) is not recommend too. Since its return is not fresh and sometimes return irrelevant results for long tail keywords(I think the api is not smart enough, hahaha~)

If you still want to use api to access fresh google SERP in python, I think you should consider about third-party api (such as serpapi, thruuu~)

If you just want the final csv result, you may try this free app "[scohalo serp analyzer](https://www.scohalo.com/serp-analyzer/)". it can crawl google serp and export the data to a csv.